# That Ain’t Rght... 1# (Definitely!)

Tags: chess, retrograde-analysis

Many chess problems are dedicated to legal games, and very few to illegal ones. So I’ve decided to start another series of the latter!

Every problem I make will have some offbeat thing about it that won’t follow normal chess rules. The position will provide you with plenty of clues as to what it is. Sometimes I will give you some clues. These chess games are meant to the wrong way!

---

Task: State the rule/s that you believe are being broken based on the position and/or what clues I have/you think are being given. You must also use this rule to complete the given game.

The Position:

What To Do: With white to move, and black to cooperate, stalemate white in ONE move!

[image]

Comment: I can stalemate with Rg8 Rh7 if the white king isn't allowed to move down rank.  I don't understand what you mean by rules being broken.  This is a legal position that could occur with normal rules, so there could be a lot of choices

Comment: @ArtemLugin It's a legal position with black to move, but not a legal position with white to move as specified.

Comment: @isaacg Why is that? Could you explain, I don't see that

Comment: @RewanDemontay I'm asking why isaacg says its not a legal position by regular rules

Comment: @RewanDemontay I'll wait for isaacg to clarify.  I believe my first comment is valid.  There are many options here.  An illegal move can be a lot of things.  Unless there are clues in the position which point to a specific illegal move being used in the past.  But since this is a perfectly valid position (maybe issacg can show me its not) the illegal move cant be narrowed down to one

Comment: @ArtemLugin In the diagram, the black rook on f8 is attacking the white king on h8. If white is to move, then the position is not legal. The position is only legal with black to move.

Comment: @isaacg I don't understand your point.  The white king is in check.  White Rg8 blocks that check.

Comment: @ArtemLugin You're right, I had everything backwards in my head. Ignore everything I said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I notice that

> There are three white rooks in play. This means that one of the rooks has come from pawn promotion.

White's strategy may therefore be

> To perform a rook demotion to a pawn (the inverse operation to balance the board). 
>  Presumably, white would play the rook to block the check. 
>  So the illegal move would be something like **Rg8=**. 
>  This piece now becomes a pawn frozen at the end of the board which allows black to play **Rf7** for stalemate

Title

> The misspelling in the title suggests that the illegal move has something to do with the g rook moving to row 8 in an improper way (That Ain't **Rg**ht... where ht may be short for *huit*, 8 in French)